# "p-adic" presentation of surfaces

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, hyperbolic-geometry, lattices-in-lie-groups

On several occasions I heard about the following result:

For "certain" lattices $\Lambda$ in $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$, and almost any prime $p$ there exists a lattice $\Gamma$ in $SL_2(\mathbb{R})\times SL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ and a compact subgroup $K$ of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})\times SL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ such that there is an isomorphism between
$$
\Lambda \backslash SL_2(\mathbb{R})
$$
and
$$
\Gamma \backslash SL_2(\mathbb{R})\times SL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)/K.
$$
I know how to prove this for $\Lambda = SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. Then $\Gamma = SL_2(\mathbb{Z}[1/p])$ (diagonally in $SL_2(\mathbb{R})\times SL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$) and $K=\{1\}\times SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ and the isomorphism is a quite easy map.

I would like to find a reference for more general $\Lambda$, preferably with an explicit statement of the isomorphism and an explanation, what means "certain". Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "isomorphism"? (could you also put parentheses in your double coset? it took me 1 minute to read it: $\Gamma\backslash (\dots\times\dots)/K$).